# cryptmount and cryptsetup difference

Tags: cryptsetup, dmcrypt

dm-crypt have a two frontends are currently available: cryptsetup and cryptmount.
Who know about cryptmount and cryptsetup difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ifnd answer, "cryptmount allows a user to mount an encrypted filing system without requiring superuser privileges, and assists the superuser in creating new encrypted filesystems." and
"cryptsetup is used to conveniently setup dm-crypt managed device-mapper mappings."